# Georeference NetCDF using rioxarray

Tags: python, rioxarray, xarray

I have a NetCDF file with a lot of variables and an improperly set georeference. Loading using `xarray` works, using `rioxarray.open_rasterio` I get the following error: `"NotGeoreferencedWarning: Dataset has no geotransform, gcps, or rpcs. The identity matrix be returned."`.
The coordinates are included as variables, but the raster is tilted so it's not straightforward to get 1D X and Y coordinates (see figure).

Any suggestions on how to save my data to a georeferenced file using these 2D coordinate arrays?

[image]